# Cloud based inventory management

Tags: inventory

I run a 15 people company with single product. Company does design, marketing and after sales support of electronic products. The first product and the upcoming ones are complex products with 100s of components. We do all the purchasing for better pricing control. We use contract manufacturers for production and we are starting to realize excel will not work for multi product solution.

I plan to invest in a tool which should:

- track component inventory
- issue POs (combining products per distributor)
- determine how many should be bought based on MoQ
- help me track finished good inventory
- help me track write offs
- help me reconcile between CM and our warehouse
- deal with multiple currencies
- preferable cloud based

I looked at a few, liked Aligni a lot but couldn't find reviews and wondering if there are better solutions out there.

Comment: Can I suggest that you also look for one that includes the following features: Time to Delivery and Price Breaks for suppliers of the same items - there will be times when ordering 1 more or being prepared to wait another day will make a big difference in costs. I would also give your designers access to a list of the components that you already purchase to consider using in their designs - if you have 10 products that use slightly different components they will be more expensive than if they use the same components, (even if the base price is higher and they are mostly over specificatioin).

Comment: @SteveBarnes that's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/) which is a solution with full customization available it provides the base modules for the following fields of activity:

- Accounting
- Invoicing
- Sale Management
- Purchase Management
- Analytic Accounting
- Inventory Management
- Manufacturing Resource Planning (MRP)
- Project Management
- Lead and Opportunity Management

It is Free, (gratis), open source & cross platform.  Written in [python](http://python.org) and using PostgreSQL as database engine.

You will have to do considerable setup & customization but there are a number of companies that can assist (for a fee) and an active community.

For a paid for SAAS solution you could take a look at [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/).